# Two point series intersect only after extended?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have two point series

```
A = [(18.405316791178798, -22.039859853332942),
 (18.372696520198463, -21.1145),
 (18.746540658574137, -20.1145),
 (18.698714698430614, -19.1145),
 (18.80081378263931, -18.1145),
 (18.838536172339943, -17.1145),
 (18.876258562040572, -16.1145),
 (18.967679510389303, -15.1145),
 (19.004907703822514, -14.1145),
 (19.042135897255729, -13.1145),
 (19.345372798084995, -12.1145),
 (19.391824245372803, -11.598937753853679),
 (19.435471418833544, -11.1145),
 (19.420235820376909, -10.1145),
 (19.423148861774159, -9.1145),
 (19.426061903171416, -8.1145),
 (19.452752569112423, -7.1145),
 (19.489649834463115, -6.1145),
 (19.444635952332344, -5.1145),
 (19.443635102001071, -5.0430597023976906),
 (19.430626347601358, -4.1145),
 (19.421676068414001, -3.1144999999999996),
 (19.362954522948439, -2.1144999999999996),
 (19.346848825989134, -1.1144999999999996),
 (19.359781116687397, -0.1144999999999996),
 (19.396797325132418, 0.69011368336827994)]

B=[(21.7744, -17.859620414326386),
 (22.7744, -17.858000854574556),
 (23.7744, -18.065164294951039),
 (24.7744, -18.051109497755608),
 (25.7744, -18.037054700560173),
 (26.7744, -18.022999903364742),
 (27.7744, -18.008945106169307),
 (28.7744, -18.014846881456318),
 (29.7744, -18.02764295838865),
 (30.7744, -18.098340990366935)]
```

**I know for sure that they will intersect, if *one* of them is to be extended *from one head*.**

Now, I wish to find their "potential" intersection. I have written a function that can find the intersection point for "already-intersected" point series:

```
# find the intersection between two line segments
# if none, return None
# else, return sequence numbers in both rep1 and rep2 and the intersection
def _findIntersection(rep1, rep2):
    x_down = [elem[0] for elem in rep1]
    y_down = [elem[1] for elem in rep1]
    x_up = [elem[0] for elem in rep2]
    y_up = [elem[1] for elem in rep2]
    for m in xrange(len(x_down)-1):
        p0 = np.array([x_down[m], y_down[m]])
        p1 = np.array([x_down[m+1], y_down[m+1]])
        for n in xrange(len(x_up)-1):
            q0 = np.array([x_up[n], y_up[n]])
            q1 = np.array([x_up[n+1], y_up[n+1]])
            try: # to ignore the parallel cases
                params = np.linalg.solve(np.column_stack((p1-p0, q0-q1)), q0-p0)
                if np.all((params >= 0) & (params <= 1)):
                    return m, n, ((p0+params[0]*(p1-p0))[0], (p0+params[0]*(p1-p0))[1])
            except:
                pass
```

So, I think what I need is to **find out which end of which point series needs to be extended.** As long as I know this, I can simply extend it and find the intersection with existing `_findIntersection()`.

We can safely assume in this problem that the two point series are **roughly** both straight lines, which implies only one intersection exists.

*I am using Python, but any generic solution is also very much welcomed!*

Answer (score 3):

I think one way of doing this is to find the functions of both lines and then using these functions, find the intersection.  Here is how I would do that using numpy (making the assumption the lines are linear):

```
import numpy as np

def find_func(x,y):
    return np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

def find_intersect(funcA, funcB):
    a = funcA[0]-funcB[0]
    b = funcB[1]-funcA[1]
    x = b / a 
    assert np.around(find_y(funcA,x),3) == np.around(find_y(funcB,x),3)
    return x, find_y(funcA,x)

def find_y(func, x):
    return func[0] * x + func[1]


#find fits
func_A = find_func(A[:,1],A[:,0])
func_B = find_func(B[:,1],B[:,0])

#find intersection
x_intersect, y_intersect = find_intersect(func_A, func_B)
```

Here is the plotted output of the approximated linear point of intersection:

[image: approximated intersection]

Comment: +1 and thanks! I have also come up with this, but the reason why I am reluctant to do so is the fitting can get into trouble when the number of points is not that big...

Comment: OK, fair enough. Thanks for the 1+!

Answer (score 2):

First off, get the regression line of each of your point series. Convert the lines into the line segments s1 and s2 by projecting the endpoints of the lines' respective point series onto the lines themselves.

Looking at the problem in terms of linear algebra, the two line segments are vectors. Unless they are paralel or colinear, multiplying each vector with a given coefficient will cause them to be extended up to the intersection point. Thus, you need to find the coefficients alpha and beta such that `alpha * s1 = beta * s2`. In other words, solve the linear equation `alpha * s1 + beta * (-s1) = 0`, as you have done already with the individual line segments.

There are three cases that you need to be aware of.

1. If the absolute values of both alpha and beta are smaller than or equal to 1, the intersection point is inside both line segments.
2. If one absolute value is <=1 but the other is >1, the intersection point i is inside only one of the two line segments (say, s2). Multiply that line segment's vector with the coefficient you have just obtained, then add the origin of the vector, to obtain the intersection point. You can then determine which endpoint in the other line segment (s1 in this case) is closer to the intersection point; the closer one is the one to be extended from.
3. If both absolute values are >1, simply find the intersection point by multiplying s1 with (alpha / beta), then adding s1[0] to that. Once the intersection point is found, simply find the closest endpoint to it on each line segment. These are the two endpoints from which the point series must be extended.